# OnGesture events are empty

Tags: windows, delphi, c++builder, gesture

I'm trying to get interactive gesture recognition (specifically, zooming and panning) working for my Delphi / C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo app.

What I've done so far:

1. Add a TGestureManager, `GestureManager1` to my form.
2. Set the form's `Touch.GestureManager` to `GestureManager1`.
3. Leave everything under `Touch.Gestures` unchecked, because I want interactive gestures (zoom and pan), not "standard" gestures.
4. Make sure that `Touch.InteractiveGestures.igZoom` is checked.
5. Assign an `OnGesture` event handler.

The `OnGesture` event handler is triggered as expected, but the event's `EventInfo.GestureID` (which is supposed to give the type of gesture - pan, zoom, etc.) is always 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Standard" gestures (the various lines and shapes under `Touch.Gestures.Standard` and "interactive" gestures (panning, zooming, rotating) are mutually exclusive.

To process "standard" or "custom" gestures", add a `TGestureManager`.

To receive "interactive" gestures, you need to *remove* the `TGestureManager`.  [This Embarcadero DocWiki article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Gesturing_Overview), which explains how gestures work in VCL and FireMonkey, specifically says:

> In order to use [Interactive Gestures](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Gesturing_Overview#Interactive_Gestures) such as zoom and rotate in a component, you do not need to associate the component with a Gesture Manager.

[This Intel article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/comparing-touch-coding-techniques-windows-8-desktop-touch-sample) has more details on Windows' various gesture interfaces.  What Delphi calls "interactive" gestures correspond to Windows' `WM_GESTURE` message.

Comment: Also, to see what gesture you have to cast in C++ (see the InteractiveGestures sample that comes with Rad Studio - `\Samples\CPP\Mobile Snippets\InteractiveGestures`.  e.g. To test for a pan gesture:  `if (EventInfo.GestureID == static_cast<short> (igiPan))`